# Accessibility for disabled button - React Native

Tags: react-native, button, accessibility, voiceover

I have one disabled button in my screen.

I gave accessibilityLabel as "Button disabled".

When I click the button, the VO is reading as "Button disabled Double Tap to activate".

It should not read Double Tap to activate for disabled buttons. Please advice. Thanks.

```
<TouchableHighlight
    accessible
    accessibilityRole="button"
    accessibilityLabel={"Button disabled"}
    style={[styles.button, style]}
    onPress={onPressHandler}
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Can you add the part of the code which doing it?

Comment: @yairmea I have added, Please check.

Comment: `disabled={true}` - just because the label says it is disabled does not mean that the system knows it is. You need to disable the button itself.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I tried this also. Still it reads "Double tap to activate".

Comment: Why dont you pass different label on disabled state?

Comment: YOu should use 2 things on button: one is disabled= {isDisabled} as well as  accessibilityState={{
            disabled: isDisabled,
          }}  to make it happen

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue.

```
 const Button: any = disabled ? View : TouchableHighlight;

<Button
    accessible
    accessibilityRole="button"
    accessibilityLabel={"Button disabled"}
    disabled={disabled}
    style={[styles.button, style]}
    onPress={onPressHandler}
</Button>
```